# Pipeline filtering and processing with lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, lodash

I have the following lodash pseudocode, that would process `auctions`:

```
var auctions = [{'item': 12345, ...}, {'item': 12345, ...}, {'item':23436, ...}];

var process = function(auctions) {
  _(auctions)
    .groupBy('item')
    .thru(processSpecialItems)
    .each(processCommonItems)
    .value();
}
```

Each function depends on the result of the previous one, but in the case of `processSpecialItems` and `processCommonItems`:

- Only specific `item`s, ie. the group identified by a given `item` value, would be processed by `processSpecialItems`.
- Only those groups who have not been processed should proceed to `processCommonItems`.
- These ops are CPU intensive and involve DB access.

Questions:

- How can I filter these special items, process them, and return the rest? Preferably with as less passes as possible, since `data` contains in excess of 40,000 items.
- Is it acceptable, performance wise, to use synchronous iteration? This snippet would be executed up to 400 times (all at the same time).

Comment: Will there be items which have to be processed by both of them?

Comment: No, please see above. Only items _not_ processed as special will move on to `processCommonItems`.

Comment: The answer depends of how much control you have over processSpecialItems, processCommonItems. Can you change their implementation?

Comment: Can you tell ahead of time which items are "special"?  Could you implement an "isSpecialItem" function?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are able to determine ahead of time which item groups would be handled by `processSpecialItems`, this is probably a job for `_.partition`.

From the [docs](https://lodash.com/docs#partition):

> Creates an array of elements split into two groups, the first of which contains elements predicate returns truthy for, the second of which contains elements predicate returns falsey for.

`_.partition(auctions, isSpecial)` would return `[specialItems, commonItems]` (where `specialItems` and `commonItems` are appropriate arrays of items). Then you can just have `processSpecialItems` operate on the first element and `processCommonItems` operate on the second.

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 0):

dont group items at first step, do next

```
var process = function(auctions) {
    return _(auctions)
    .partition(function(obj) {
        // use here partition condition, 
        // which return true for special item,
        // something like 
        return _.startsWith(obj.item, 's');
    })
    // you receive array of 2 arrays where
    // first array - array of special items
    // second array - array of common items
    .thru(function(array){ // process items
        return [
            _.map(array[0], functionToProcessSpecialItem),
            _.map(array[1], functionToProcessCommonItem)
        ];
    })
    .flatten() // flat result
    .groupBy('item') // and group
    .value(); // you receive grouped and processed auctions
}
```